# LibGdx switching between multiple UI panels

Tags: libgdx, software-engineering, scene2d

Let's say I have a game screen with a game world stage and UI stage. UI has a build button in the corner which should open a full screen build menu window/panel while hiding game world and the previously visible UI icons. In the build menu, user can click close button or select a building. Both of these actions would return the user to the main game screen. How should this be handled in LibGdx?

I tried making separate stages for main game UI and build menu and add event listeners in appropriate buttons which notify subscribed stages whether it should be displayed or not. But the code became very messy setting lots of booleans everywhere. Maybe I should use just one stage for main UI and build menu and just add and remove actors when switching between these UI elements? But I am not sure how to do this without manually removing a hundred of actors from the main UI while adding hundred of actors in the build menu one by one.

Is there a standard elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe I should implement each major UI panel using separate Screen? When switchin between screens, I would pass the parent screen to child screen as reference and would not dispose of it. Is this a good way to implement UI in libgdx?